# Rescaling image in J2ME

Tags: image, java-me

I'm resizing a bird image using the following code:

> private Image resizeImage(Image src) {
>
> ```
>     int srcWidth = src.getWidth();
>
>     int srcHeight = src.getHeight();
>
>     int screenWidth=getWidth()/3;
>
>     int screenHeight=getHeight()/3;
>
>     Image tmp = Image.createImage(screenWidth, srcHeight);
>
>     Graphics g = tmp.getGraphics();
>
>     int ratio = (srcWidth << 16) / screenWidth;
>
>     int pos = ratio/2;
>
>     //Horizontal Resize        
>
>     for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++) {
>         g.setClip(x, 0, 1, srcHeight);
>         g.drawImage(src, x - (pos >> 16), 0, Graphics.LEFT | Graphics.TOP);
>         pos += ratio;
>     }
>
>     Image resizedImage = Image.createImage(screenWidth, screenHeight);
>     g = resizedImage.getGraphics();
>     ratio = (srcHeight << 16) / screenHeight;
>     pos = ratio/2;        
>
>     //Vertical resize
>
>     for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++) {
>         g.setClip(0, y, screenWidth, 1);
>         g.drawImage(tmp, 0, y - (pos >> 16), Graphics.LEFT | Graphics.TOP);
>         pos += ratio;
>     }
>     return resizedImage;
> ```
>
> [image]
>       }

The image is resized but it has white background along with it as shown. How to get only resized image with transparent background..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an Image scaling function I've been using. Includes transparency. Found here: http://willperone.net/Code/codescaling.php

```
public Image scale(Image original, int newWidth, int newHeight) {

 int[] rawInput = new int[original.getHeight() * original.getWidth()];
 original.getRGB(rawInput, 0, original.getWidth(), 0, 0, original.getWidth(), original.getHeight());

 int[] rawOutput = new int[newWidth * newHeight];

 // YD compensates for the x loop by subtracting the width back out
 int YD = (original.getHeight() / newHeight) * original.getWidth() - original.getWidth();
 int YR = original.getHeight() % newHeight;
 int XD = original.getWidth() / newWidth;
 int XR = original.getWidth() % newWidth;
 int outOffset = 0;
 int inOffset = 0;

 for (int y = newHeight, YE = 0; y > 0; y--) {
   for (int x = newWidth, XE = 0; x > 0; x--) {
     rawOutput[outOffset++] = rawInput[inOffset];
     inOffset += XD;
     XE += XR;
     if (XE >= newWidth) {
       XE -= newWidth;
       inOffset++;
     }
   }
   inOffset += YD;
   YE += YR;
   if (YE >= newHeight) {
     YE -= newHeight;
     inOffset += original.getWidth();
   }
 }
 rawInput = null;
 return Image.createRGBImage(rawOutput, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. I tried this method. Now i can see black pixels instead of white pixels as the background.. Its not transaparent.

Comment: That is very strange. I've used it successfully for our latest game piratediamonds.com, both with 8-bit and 24-bit PNG files. Remember to put "true" as the last parameter in the return Image.createRGBImage method.

Comment: Its working now.. But on device its taking time to resize. Any algorithm to make it faster?

Comment: I don't think so. That function is one of the optimized variations already.